# How does Github generate small branch diffs?

Tags: git, github, diff

Let's say I work on a project in the following order:

1. Fork master to branch named BRANCH-A
2. Merge BRANCH-B to master
3. Merge BRANCH-C to master
4. Do some work on BRANCH-A and submit a pull request

Now, if I checkout BRANCH-A locally and run `git diff master`, the diff will include files from BRANCH-B and BRANCH-C which are in master but not in my branch.

However, if I check the same diff on Github, it excludes the changes from BRANCH-B and BRANCH-C when generating a list of changed files, and a visual diff.

How does Github generate this diff? How can I reproduce it at the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a diff between the point where a branch was branched of [1] and the current head of a branch [by separating both names with three dots](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#_examples): `git diff master...a`

Compare:

```
[timwolla@/t/test (a)]git diff master..a
diff --git a/a b/a
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..e69de29
diff --git a/a2 b/a2
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..e69de29
diff --git a/b b/b
deleted file mode 100644
index e69de29..0000000
diff --git a/c b/c
deleted file mode 100644
index e69de29..0000000
```

---

```
[timwolla@/t/test (a)]git diff master...a
diff --git a/a b/a
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..e69de29
diff --git a/a2 b/a2
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..e69de29
```

[1] It's the “newest” common ancestor and can be retrieved via: `git merge-base master a`. You could also have used `git diff $(git merge-base master a)` to achieve the same effect as the three dots.